# How to do calculation in drupal views?

Tags: php, database, drupal-7, view, calculated-columns

I want know how to calculate the values in views from existing fields by adding views php, or I have to use views api or by creating templates.Which approach will be best for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want simple math calculations, then I would look at [views calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc).  Views PHP has some great uses for quick testing, but it is generally assumed that if you need Views PHP you should write your own module.  You can also get a good discussion on this issue at: https://www.drupal.org/node/1219356.

Comment: Yes I have done that by creating templates of views php fields.
Thanks Kevin